# Weird Wi-Fi related issues affecting "Now Playing", media keys and the Maps app

Tags: macos, wifi, notifications, touch-bar, maps

This is my first post here because I'm out of ideas. I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2018, i9, 32GB RAM, Radeon Pro 560X.

I believe all of the following symptoms are related to some weird Wi-Fi issue my MacBook Pro is having:

1. My Maps app can't locate me even when I'm on Wi-Fi.
2. If I turn off Wi-Fi or don't have a Wi-Fi connection, the "Now Playing" Widget on my Touch Bar and in the Notification Center do not work at all, not even for playing local media files.
3. When my "Now Playing"  widget does not work (as per 2 above), my media keys/headphone controls controlling iTunes also don't work.

So far I have tried:

- booting in Safe Mode
- resetting the SMC and NVRAM
- turned  location services on/off
- restarting my router

For the record I don't have Spotify or Google Chrome installed, nor do I have any extensions installed.

How else might I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I've edited your question to change the tags and to try and clarify it and make it easier to read. I'm also conscious that your question does *seem* to be about different issues (normally this site works best when each question is about a single issue), so my edit does try to tie it all in to what you believe is a *"weird Wi-Fi issue"* that's causing all of these problems. However, it is possible that these are in fact totally separate issues and may need to be dealt with separately. For now though, we'll see how this goes.

Comment: Please check my edit to make sure I haven't got anything wrong, as I've read in between the lines a little. If I do have something wrong, please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/368322/edit) your question to correct these. All the best!